# How to get property value from IEnumerable<object>

Tags: c#, .net, ienumerable, ienumerator

I have a method which returns IEnumerable

```
public static IEnumerable<object> GetProps<T>(T obj)
    {        
        var result = obj.GetType().GetProperties()
            .Select(x => new { property = x.Name, value = x.GetValue(obj) })
            .Where(x => x.value == null)
            .ToList();
        return result;
    }
```

Above code will return result as `[{"property":"YearOfBirth","value":null}]`

I;m now trying to get property value**YearOfBirth** from the returned result.
Can someone please suggest/help ?

Comment: Isn't the value always `null`?

Comment: Some [edit] would clarify question - so far title asks for "name" ("How to get property name ..." and body asks for value ("get value YearOfBirth") and code always return null for all properties it detected (`.Where(x => x.value == null)`).

Comment: updated the question..I should have mentioned this earlier....YearOfBirth is not consistent...this value is dynamic and I have not control over this value

Comment: What is the `obj` used to call `GetProps()` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The type of:

```
new { property = x.Name, value = x.GetValue(obj) }
```

is an anonymous type and you can't access fields or properties of that anonymous type outside of the function where it was defined, without using reflection.  Here's how you would access its properties using reflection:

```
foreach (object prop in GetProps(obj))
{
    string propertyName = prop.GetType().GetProperty("property").GetValue(prop);
    object propertyValue = prop.GetType().GetProperty("value").GetValue(prop);
}
```

But that's not really the best solution.  You don't care about the property value, since you're just returning ones where it's null.  So a better solution is IEnumerable<string>:

```
public static IEnumerable<string> GetProps<T>(T obj)
{        
    var result = obj.GetType().GetProperties()
        .Select(x => new { property = x.Name, value = x.GetValue(obj) })
        .Where(x => x.value == null)
        .Select(x => x.property)
        .ToList();
    return result;
}
```

If you really want to return the property name with its value, I suggest using ValueTuple syntax instead of anonymous types, which will let you access the property and value fields of the ValueTuple (requires C# 7):

```
public static IEnumerable<(string property, object value)> GetProps<T>(T obj)
{        
    var result = obj.GetType().GetProperties()
        .Select(x => ( x.Name, x.GetValue(obj) ) })
        .Where(x => x.Item2 == null)
        .ToList();
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var yearOfBirth = GetProps(someObject)
    .FirstOrDefault(x => x.property == "YearOfBirth")?.value;
```

Something like that.

You could alternatively just do:

```
dynamic someObjectDynamic = someObject;
var yearOfBirth = someObjectDynamic.YearOfBirth;
```

Comment: Updated the question
I should have mentioned this earlier....YearOfBirth is not consistent...this value is dynamic and I have not control over this value

Comment: That rules out the dynamic approach, but you can still use the first example in any case you know what property name you are looking for. If you don't know what property name you are looking for, then I can't think of any reliable way you will be able to get its value. ML classification of the properties based on their likelihood of being a year of birth field? Wouldn't recommend it. I see your account is new, its considered polite to upvote any answers that seem relevant ;)

Comment: Also, why is .Where(x => x.value == null) there? That means it will only return properties (and their values) for the property values that are null.

Comment: Yes, I want it to return only when null